# How to reference a variable from a mat file numerically in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, variables

I am writing a script for MatLab where a *.mat file is loaded using the load command to the workspace. My problem is I am not sure how to reference a variable name. I know what data i need based on the size commmand but I need a means of referring to a variable numerically. Maybe as an index like the first in the list has an index of 1 or something. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "reference numerically"? Do you mean [_array indexing_](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html)?

Comment: so an example would be I load a mat file and it has 3 variables. The names might be different depending on the mat file loaded but the sizes are the same between the files. So I am trying to avoid hardcoding names into my script and would prefer doing something like "temp = 2nd variable in the workspace" That way i do not need to know about the specific names to run my code. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description is not very clear, do you mean you want to access the variables loaded from a MAT-file by index? something like the following:

```
%# load all variables of MAT-file in a structure
S = load('myfile.mat');
fn = fieldnames(S);

%# get a variable by index
idx = 1;
x = S.(fn{idx})
```

Of course it would make more sense if the variables names are sorted first: `fn = sort(fn)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `whos` to look at the contents of a `.mat` file.  For example:

```
%Create some data in a file
cd(tempdir);
x=rand(5,5);
y=rand(6,6);
save someFile x y

%Then look at the variable metadata within that file.
varMeta = whos('-file','someFile')
varMeta = 
2x1 struct array with fields:
    name
    size
    bytes
    class
    global
    sparse
    complex
    nesting
    persistent
```

Then you can apply whatever logic is needed on the `size` field to determine whoch variable you are looking for.